# Org-mode: How to display current time record in another color?

Tags: org-mode, faces, themes

I'm still very new to emacs and currently use it on the terminal to track my work time in org-mode.

```
** Save the world
:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2019-02-14 Do 10:24]
CLOCK: [2019-02-14 Do 08:51]--[2019-02-14 Do 09:28] =>  0:37
```

How could I make it display the currently running time record in a different color or bold to make it more visible?
I'm aware that I can also see the current task in the status line.

Comment: You can make something bold by just putting it between asterisks, *like this*. Does that work for you?

Comment: @jesse I'm looking for a color scheme option or something like a style rule in the color scheme that matches only the currently active time record line. So that would not work for me. Thank you though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code puts an overlay with red bold face on the running clock whenever you call `org-clock-in`. It removes the overlay when you call `org-clock-out`.

I am not entirely sure whether that is the right thing for you since the `LOGBOOK` drawer is not shown by default.
But the code could easily be adapted such that the overlay is put on the heading with running clock.

```el
(require 'org-element)
(require 'org-clock)

(defvar org-clock-running-ol nil
  "Overlay for the running clock.")

(defface org-clock-running-face
  '((t :foreground "Red" :weight bold))
  "Face for highlighting the running clock.")

(defun org-clock-add-running-ol ()
  "Highlight the running clock."
  (save-excursion
    (when (org-clock-is-active)
      (org-clock-remove-running-ol)
      (goto-char org-clock-marker)
      (setq org-clock-running-ol (make-overlay (point) (scan-sexps (point) -1)))
      (overlay-put org-clock-running-ol 'face 'org-clock-running-face)
      )))

(defun org-clock-remove-running-ol ()
  (when (overlayp org-clock-running-ol)
    (delete-overlay org-clock-running-ol)
    (setq org-clock-running-ol nil)))

(add-hook 'org-clock-in-hook #'org-clock-add-running-ol)
(add-hook 'org-clock-out-hook #'org-clock-remove-running-ol)
```

Comment: Wow, just works. Since I unfold all folds in evil mode with `zR` it's ok for me like this and I can use it as a base to learn more myself.

Answer (score 0):

I think changing the color for `org-clock-overlay` is what you are looking for.

Just <kbd>M-x</kbd><kbd>list-faces-display</kbd> RET to see a list with all the faces. Search for `org-clock-overlay` and customize it the way you want.

Comment: I have tried that but it changes the color of all time records, including the ones that have finished/have an end time. I want only the active one, the one that is missing an end time. However, I'm quite astonished what nice UI emacs gives me to edit the theme. :)